# Plot chart is not working with JSON data PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I display the data coming from a JSON in the chart correctly? Because the way I'm trying does not work.
The format of the data to display on the graph has to be this way [[key, value]], if I put the static data this way it works:

```
data: [
    ["Jan", 1],
    ["Fev", 2],
    ["Mar", 3],
    ["Abr", 4],
    ["Mai", 5],
    ["Jun", 6],
    ["Jul", 6],
    ["Ago", 6],
    ["Set", 6],
    ["Out", 6],
    ["Nov", 6],
    ["Dez", 6],   
]
```

But if I send a json it does not work:

```
{"data":{"Jan":"0","Fev":"0","Mar":"1","Abr":"0","Mai":"9","Jun":"4","Jul":"0","Ago":"0","Set":"0","Out":"0","Nov":"0","Dez":"0"}}
```

This is the javascript code that loads the graphic:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path + 'admin/chart/get_user_twelve_months',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);

        var flotDashSales1Data = [{
            data: [
                response.data
            ],
            color: "#2baab1"
        }];

        var flotDashSales1 = $.plot('#chart_user_twelve_months', flotDashSales1Data, {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                labelMargin: 15,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: 'categories',
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: {
                content: '%x: %y',
                shifts: {
                    x: -30,
                    y: 25
                },
                defaultTheme: false
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If needed, json comes from PHP

```
    public function get_user_twelve_months()
    {
        $current_year = date('Y');
        $responseseries = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $query = "SELECT count(id_user) AS total FROM user
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = {$current_year} AND MONTH(created_at) = {$i}";

            $result = $this->db->query($query)->result()[0];
            $total = ($result->total) ? $result->total : "0";

            $month_name = get_month_name($i);
            $responseseries['data'][$month_name] = $total;
        }


        $json = json_encode($responseseries);
        return $json;
    }
```

Comment: You send `object` but expect `array of arrays`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: So I would have to convert json @fen1x ?

Comment: Yes. Try this `Object.keys(obj).map( (key) => [key, Number(obj[key])] )`.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thank you!